# Flash Var Loader Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, flashvars

I have three classes and a container .swf:
Game - this loads all assets and game mechanics.
Tile - Creates a square and loads image an image via flash Var.
TicTacToe.as - This creates a game instance and is linked via container.swf

In my Game class I have the following code which works fine when I save and compile, and is able to load my images when I update to my .asp page(I am getting the data from a db and passing to flash vars).

```
var gridUrl:String = "img/" + loaderInfo.parameters.theme + "grid.png";
            var gridPos:XMLList = theXML.GRID;
            gridLoader.load(new URLRequest(gridUrl));
            grid = new MovieClip();
            grid.addChild(gridLoader);
```

When I add this code to the Tile.as to load an image for the square I get a compiler error 1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. with an error on this line:

```
var tileBurl:String = "img/" + loaderInfo.parameters.theme + "square.jpg";
```

Its working in the Game.as class but this same line isn't in my Tile.as and I can't figure out why, even locally when it can't find the variables Game.as simply lists them as "undefined" where as in Tile.as it throws a fit at loaderInfo.parameters, and loaderInfo lists them as "null". Any Help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Pass `loaderInfo`' reference to your `Tile` object

Comment: Thanks for your response Cherniv, I do have a reference at the start of my class import flash.display.LoaderInfo; but issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that in the time of calling *loaderInfo* object, this is not yet prepared. Try to delay execution of the code for example by adding empty frame at the begining.

Comment: Thanks Laky, so in my container.swf I do have a blank keyframe on frame 1, are you saying to add another on frame 2? I do have a Class that is connected to this .swf, none if this code is contained within it.

Comment: What about adding scene with preloader?

Comment: ah that might work, and probably the way I should have started out. I will use a preloader to load the assets first. So i would have some function in my Game.as file to check if the data is loaded, like Event.Complete then fire the rest of the code right?